# Keil Studio: How to change the location where the output files on my laptop?

Tags: c++, embedded, keil, mbed

If I Build or Download the file, it always download in the location: Download without any file options.

How to set the location to output any files from the specific project on Keil Studio?

I hope that I could download files in the location where I want to

Answer (score 0):

Keil Studio Cloud will download files to the chosen download directory set by your web browser. Unfortunately it is not possible to choose a different location at present.

Comment: In some browsers (like Chrome) you can tell the browser to always ask where to download things to, but this is a global setting that would apply to all websites and web apps.